# TFS Sharepoint site creation fails

Tags: sharepoint, templates, tfs, portal

I have created a template to use as team project portal template. However, when I try to create a project with portal from this template, I get an error message saying :

```
Module: WSS
Exception Message: TF249033: The site template is not available for the locale identifier (LCID). The site template name is: _GLOBAL_#0. The LCID is: 1033. (type TeamFoundationServerException)
```

The language on the server os is 1033, the language of the WSS installation is 1033 and the language of TFS is also 1033.

What is wrong here. Any hints at a possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are creating a project from a template supplied with TFS or a custom template?

Comment: A custom template. stsadm -enumtemplates gives me also 1033 as language for the template.

Comment: Scrum for team system, perchance?

Comment: I created a project site with the Agile template, edited it, and created a template to use for all team project portals.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation from a web search seems to be to either reinstall SharePoint, or install the SharePoint Language Pack for your installation.  I'd probably start with the latter.

Comment: I can confirm that those tipps are not working. Reinstalling is IMO not a tipp for a real-life-scenario :-(.